# robolectric and lottie: what's the correct way to verify that an animation is playing?

Tags: android, robolectric, animator

I am trying to use Robolectric to verify that a Lottie animation is playing.

ExampleUnitTest.java:

```
@Test
public void lottie_isAnimating() {
    MainActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);

    LottieAnimationView lottieAnimationView = (LottieAnimationView) activity.findViewById(R.id.lottieanimation);

    assertTrue(lottieAnimationView.isAnimating()); // fails here
}
```

This doesn't work.  However, I know that the animation does run since I can see it running, and my added AnimatorListener indicates as such:

MainActivity.java:

```
lottieAnimationView.addAnimatorListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationStart():  lottieAnimationView.isAnimating() = " + lottieAnimationView.isAnimating());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationEnd():  lottieAnimationView.isAnimating() = " + lottieAnimationView.isAnimating());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationCancel():  lottieAnimationView.isAnimating() = " + lottieAnimationView.isAnimating());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onAnimationRepeat():  lottieAnimationView.isAnimating() = " + lottieAnimationView.isAnimating());
    }
});
```

The log output shows:

```
D/com.wuziq.lottierobolectrictest.MainActivity: onAnimationStart():  lottieAnimationView.isAnimating() = true
D/com.wuziq.lottierobolectrictest.MainActivity: onAnimationUpdate():  lottieAnimationView.isAnimating() = true
...
D/com.wuziq.lottierobolectrictest.MainActivity: onAnimationRepeat():  lottieAnimationView.isAnimating() = true
...
D/com.wuziq.lottierobolectrictest.MainActivity: onAnimationEnd():  lottieAnimationView.isAnimating() = true
```

I'm not clear on why onAnimationEnd() is called, but I do not stop the animation anywhere.  I am handwaving it as a side effect of how Robolectric treats animators, but I'd like to understand this.

In my test, I could simply add an AnimationListener to the LottieAnimationView and assert that onAnimationStart() and onAnimationRepeat() get called, but this seems like a hacky workaround.

What's the correct way to test this?  I feel like I'm missing something super obvious..

Sample is at https://github.com/wuziq/LottieRobolectricTest

Comment: I would not test animations with Robolectric. It might be such pain. I would test that you start animation or do something on animation end/cancel callback. And separately maybe also check that you setup animation correctly.